# SSH over HTTP with ProxyTunnel "Socket read error: [104] Connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, apache, ssh

I am trying to connect to my SSH server over HTTP through my apache web server, I have followed the instructions in guides such as [1] and [2], The tunnel connects and for ~1 minute I get a SSH connection to my server.

However, there seems to be a 60 second timeout somewhere in the chain because I get the error `Socket read error: [104] Connection reset by peer` after about 60 seconds. This happends both when I run the ssh command as configured and when I run the `proxytunnel` command in isolation.

I have attempted to fix this issue by changing the `ServerAliveInterval` to 30 seconds and enabling `TCPKeepAlive` in the `.ssh/config` file, as well as putting a `ProxyTimeout 3600` in the apache config, which I include below.

`ProxyRequests On
AllowConnect 22
ProxyTimeout 3600
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Proxy>
<ProxyMatch 127.0.0.1>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</ProxyMatch>`

Thanks for any help.

[1] http://dag.wiee.rs/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/

[2] http://blog.cppse.nl/apache-proxytunnel-ssh-tunnel

edit: I am running Apache 2.4

Answer (score 1):

As there was no exact question, here is how I fixed this problem for my servers (when I want to access it from any computer worldwide):

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/shellinabox/

The 'shell-in-a-box' emulates a ssh shell which can be called from any browser (I tested chrome and firefox).

Good install tutorial here:

http://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/

And don't forget to remove the '--localhost-only'

```
# if you want to restrict access to shellinaboxd from localhost only
SHELLINABOX_ARGS="--o-beep -s /:SSH:172.16.25.125 --localhost-only"
```

in the config file

```
/etc/default/shellinabox
```

in order to be able to access it from outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

It could work by setting with the following in the apache configuration

```
 RequestReadTimeout header=0,MinRate=500 body=0,MinRate=500
```

see https://sourceforge.net/p/proxytunnel/mailman/message/33649006/